# trouble to understand Comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have trouble to understand this code i study with. How would be the code in "normal" for loops ?

1:

```
a, b = zip(*[(X, X_type) for X_list, X_type in zip(df['X_seq'], df['type']) for X in X_list])
```

and 2:

```
for j in range(0,2):
    X_seq += zip(*(X_list[i:] for i in range(3)))
```

i tried it on my own but i get always error or other results. And there is this zip function which complicates it even more...

Thank you in advanced

Comment: Where is this code from, and what problem is it solving?

Comment: its a example  from a foil at the shool. The code is for preprocessing Data in ml

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy youre right, im so sorry !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First example:

```
a, b = zip(*[                              #         5
    (X, X_type)                            #       4
         for X_list, X_type in zip(        #   2
             df['X_seq'], df['type'])      # 1
         for X in X_list                   #     3
])
```

is a short form of

```
tups = []
# 1 - iterate over the length of the dataframe columns
#     (should be the same for X_seq and type)
for i in range(len(df['X_seq'])):
    # 2 - Take the corresponding values from X_seq and type,
    #     and put them in variables named X_list and X_type, respectively
    X_list = df['X_seq'][i]
    X_type = df['type'][i]
    # 3 - Iterate over X_list
    for X in X_list:
        # 4 - for each X, make a 2-tuple of (X, X_type).
        #     This will result in duplicating X_type for as many
        #     values of X as there are in X_list.
        tups.append((X, X_type))
# 5 - `zip(*2diterable)` is a trick that essentially flips
#     the given iterable - if it was (N x 2), then it's now (2 x N)
#     See also a tutorial on the 'unpacking operator', as it's called:
#         https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/packing-and-unpacking-arguments-in-python/
#     To do this manually:
a, b = [], []
for row in tups:
    a.append(row[0])
    b.append(row[1])
```

---

Second example:

```
for j in range(0,2):                      # 1
    X_seq +=                              #       4
        zip(*(                            #     3
            X_list[i:] for i in range(3)  #   2
    ))
```

is a short form of

```
# assume X_seq exists already and is a list
# 1 - same for loop as in your given example
for j in range(0, 2):
    # 2 - list comprehension over range(3). For each index, take a 
    #     sublist of X_list consisting of every element whose index
    #     is equal or greater.
    seg = []
    for i in range(3):  # iterates over [0, 1, 2]
        seg.append(X_list[i:])
    # 3 - unpacking operator again. zip() groups corresponding
    #     elements, but is limited by the shortest list it's given
    zipped = []
    for i in range(len(seg[2]):  # seg[2] will be the shortest
        zipped.append(
            (seg[0][i], seg[1][i], seg[2][i])
        )
    # 4 - list concatenation. Append each tuple in zipped to X_seq
    for tup in zipped:
        X_seq.append(tup)
```

---

This is the best I can do. I have no context for what this code is trying to accomplish, and if you copy/paste any of this it shouldn't suddenly start working if it wasn't already. But maybe this will make it somewhat easier for you to debug whatever is wrong with the process in your code.

Comment: I sense a slight mismatch between effort put into the question and effort put into the answer. Anyway, good answer!

Comment: @timgeb eh, list comprehensions are confusing. Especially when you mix the `zip(*iterable)` idiom in with them. Understandable to have no idea what's going on.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy Thank you ! it works.Now i understand how Comprehensions work (and also why you need this). I never thought i would it understand via stackoverflow, but youre an Angel. You are my hero of today. Thank you very much!